# Collections not working in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, varray

By below code is not working for cursor on PLSQL.
I receive an error message.

---

```
 declare 
      type abc is varray(10) of number;
      cursor x is select Empno from emp where rownum <10;
      a abc;
      counter  number :=1;
    begin
      a:=abc();
     for i in x
     loop
      a.extend();
      a(i):=counter.Empno;
      DBMS_output.put_line(a(i));
      counter:=  end loop;
    end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used `counter` instead of `for loop iterator` `i`:

Try;

```
declare 
    type abc is varray(10) of number;
    cursor x is select Empno from emp where rownum <10;
    a abc;
    counter number := 1;
begin
    a:=abc();
    for i in x loop
        a.extend();
        a(counter) := i.Empno;
        DBMS_output.put_line(a(counter));
        counter := counter + 1;
    end loop;
end;
```

Or you can use [`Bulk collect`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/bulk-binds-and-record-processing-9i) to insert data into `varray`

```
declare 
    type abc is varray(10) of number;
    a abc := abc();        
begin  
    select Empno BULK COLLECT INTO a from emp where rownum <10;
    for i in 1 .. a.count loop 
        DBMS_output.put_line(a(i)); 
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: When there is no data in the table. I get a error during runtime.
what would be the exception ?

Comment: Error report -
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 6
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints.

Comment: this is because of collection (varray) is empty then a.first and a.last will return null....... Please see the updated answer......